# strongloop REST API filter where like clause. is it possible to make it case insensitive

Tags: strongloop

Hello I'm new to loopback and i'm trying to create a REST query filter like this that ignores casing:

> /api/customers?filter[include]=profiles&filter[where][Name][like]=Com

This above works perfectly as long as the person uses the proper casing. I was wondering if there is a flag or a way to make this query ignore the casing?

BTW the datasource is MongoDB

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pending PR https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/32  please feel free to add comments on there.